# ASP.NET Events Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, textbox

When I run my app local through the debug button my text box changed event fires after typing something in the text box and tabbing off of it.

But if I deploy to an IIS sever and test the site, the event doesn't fire.

What could be causing this problem?

UPDATE*** Sorry for the confusion. This has nothing to do with DEBUGGING and BREAKPOINTS. The events won't fire at all when deployed to IIS but they do fire when running locally

Comment: Ok, are you talking about ASP.Net events or Javascript events?

Comment: Are you attaching VS to your `w3wp.exe` process to debug the events?

Comment: @ChrisHardie ASP.NET events

Comment: How do you know that the event does not fire?

Comment: @KarlAnderson what does VS stand for? Visual Studio?

Comment: @MobileMon - Yes, VS = Visual Studio.

Comment: @Igor - I am guessing he has a break point on his event handler that was firing when he was F5 running his code, but now that he has deployed to IIS when he runs the code in the browser it is not hitting the break point, which is why I asked if he has attached to the IIS process (w3wp.exe).

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have which does not appear to be working?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

After deploying your code to IIS and launching the website in your browser of choice, then go to the `Debug` menu in Visual Studio and choose `Attach To Process...`. This will open up a dialog window where processes are listed, check the box `Show processes from all users.` and then locate the `w3wp.exe` process in the list, now click the `Attach` button. It will take a little bit of time (seconds, not minutes) to load the symbols and make your break points active. Now when you generate events and have their handlers breakpointed on the server-side, the debugger will stop at the breakpoints just like when you pressed F5 in Visual Studio before deploying to IIS.

For more information read [Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx)

Comment: It's not a problem specific to DEBUGGING after I deploy to IIS. I simply can't get the events to fire period after deploying to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really the standard behaviour that the event gets fired automatically after you tab out.
For this to happen you have to say that the textbox should autopostback.

You should declare your asp:net textbox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="helloWorldTextBox" runat="server" Text="Hello World!" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="helloWorldTextBox_TextChanged" />
```

If I understood you correctly you arent facing the problem of not being able to debug it, but simple that what ever should happen on the TextChanged Event isnt doing what it should do.

Another thing, if you are creating the textbox dynamically (in code behind) you have to make sure that the ID stays the same or the event wont fire. This is normally done in the Page_Init Event.

Comment: I got the impression that he was able to successfully debug the code when running `Personal Web Development Server` or `IIS Express`, but then when he deployed to IIS on his machine, then his debugging stopped working. If   I am wrong, then my answer is useless and I will delete it.

Comment: Dont think so, but we wont know for sure until MobileMon answers. :) I saw your answer and comments on his page, but I didnt get this idea after reading his question. Its more like "why is nothing happening on IIS, but while running in Visual Studio it works...", but as I said sooner or later we will know for sure. :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I updated my question accordingly. This has nothing to do with DEBUGGING and BREAKPOINTS. The events won't fire at all when deployed to IIS but they do fire when running locally

Comment: I have autopostback set to true and I don't create the textbox programatically

Comment: Than you need to post your html markup and the code behind, its not supposed to be this case and we cant figure it out without the code/html.